# User not logging in. Template cannot access the user attributes

Tags: django, authentication

I am pretty new ατ Django. I have been trying to develop a user authentication for my app. For which I am using `AuthenticationForm` for form and a FormView for the login view. I have also built a custom Backend which authenticates users using email address instead of username. Authentication seems to work fine because it returns a user object when supplied with correct email and password and shows an error otherwise. And the `form_valid()`takes me to the '`success_url`'. But when I try to access the user attributes like name or email, I cannot access them in the template (success_url). And the `user.is_authenticated` seems to return False. What could be wrong? I have spent hours trying to fix this, but no success yet. I would highly appreciate your guidence and suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Here is my `LoginView:`

class LoginView(FormView):

```
form_class = AuthenticationForm
success_url = "hello/"
#redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
template_name = 'draint_user/login.html'

@method_decorator(csrf_protect)
@method_decorator(never_cache)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form):
    """
    The user has provided valid credentials (this was checked in AuthenticationForm.is_valid()). So now we
    can check the test cookie stuff and log him in.
    """
    self.check_and_delete_test_cookie()
    user = form.get_user()
    login(self.request, user)
    print form.get_user().name
    return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form):
    """
    The user has provided invalid credentials (this was checked in AuthenticationForm.is_valid()). So now we
    set the test cookie again and re-render the form with errors.
    """
    self.set_test_cookie()
    return super(LoginView, self).form_invalid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    if self.success_url:
        redirect_to = self.success_url
    else:
        redirect_to = self.request.REQUEST.get(self.redirect_field_name, '')

    netloc = urlparse.urlparse(redirect_to)[1]
    if not redirect_to:
        redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    # Security check -- don't allow redirection to a different host.
    elif netloc and netloc != self.request.get_host():
        redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    return redirect_to

def set_test_cookie(self):
    self.request.session.set_test_cookie()

def check_and_delete_test_cookie(self):
    if self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
        self.request.session.delete_test_cookie()
        return True
    return False

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Same as django.views.generic.edit.ProcessFormView.get(), but adds test cookie stuff
    """
    self.set_test_cookie()
    return super(LoginView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the view for the success_url:

```
def hello(request):
    return render(request,"draint_user/hello.html",{})
```

And Here is my hello.html (the template )

```
<body>
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.get_username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is no `user` in template context. You can add it by hand or add whole request into context by activating `django.core.context_processors.request` context processor.

**In response to comment:**

1. You can define `get_context_data` in your view to add `user` object into your context:

   ```
       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           # getting default context for view
           context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

           # adding user into context
           context['user'] = self.request.user

           # returning new context
           return context
   ```
2. You can edit your settings.py file and add

   ```
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
       "django.core.context_processors.debug",
       "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
       "django.core.context_processors.media",
       "django.core.context_processors.static",
       "django.core.context_processors.tz",
       "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
       "django.core.context_processors.request",
   )
   ```

(this is default `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` from django 1.7 with added `django.core.context_processors.request` into it) or if you have already defined `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings, just add `django.core.context_processors.request` into it. Now you will able to access `request.user` in each of your templates.

Comment: I did not really get your point. I mean how should I do it, should do something in settings.py?

Comment: This is just not true. The `auth` context processor, which is a default and is listed first in the settings snippet you show, adds `auth` to the context. The request one only adds `request`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, reading from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

> render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

So you can try access the user object as `request.user` inside your template